# From concavity to second derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x)$ be continuous and differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. I want to show that if $f(x)$ is concave, then $f''(x)\le0$ $\forall\space x\in\mathbb{R}$

Proof:

Let $x,y$ be fixed in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $y>x$

Without loss of generality, since $f$ is concave, then $f'(x)\ge\cfrac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$ by the calculus criterion.

By the mean value theorem, $\exists\space c\in[x,y]$ such that $f'(c)=\cfrac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$

So I now have: $f'(x)\ge f'(c)$

Since $x$ was arbitrarily chosen, then we have shown $a\ge b\implies f'(b)\ge f'(a)$

Since $y>x$, then we have $f'(x)\ge f'(y)$ and this is true for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

So $f''(x)\le 0$

Is my approach correct?

Comment: "Since $x$ was arbitrarily chosen, then we have shown $a\ge b\implies f'(b)\ge f'(a)$".  This does not follow.  $x$ may be arbitrarily chosen, but $c$ certainly was not.  What you have shown is that for a given $x$ there is some $c>x$ with $f'(x)\ge f'(c)$ which is not as strong as you claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the incorrect reasoning after you apply the MVT, you need to assume that $f$ is twice differentiable, since not all concave functions are.

For $x_1 < x < y < x_2$ and $f$ concave you can show that

$$\tag{1}\frac{f(x) - f(x_1)}{x-x_1} \geqslant \frac{f(x_2) - f(y)}{x_2 -y}$$

Taking limits as $x \to x_1+$ and $y \to x_2-$ we get

$$f'(x_1) \geqslant f'(x_2),$$

showing that $f'$ is decreasing and $f''(x) \leqslant 0$.

**Proof of (1)**

If $x_1 < x < y$ then

$$x = \frac{y - x}{y - x_1}x_1 + \frac{x-x_1}{y-x_1}y$$

By concavity

$$f(x) \geqslant \frac{y - x}{y - x_1}f(x_1) + \frac{x-x_1}{y-x_1}f(y)$$

Hence,

$$f(x) - f(x_1) \geqslant \left(\frac{y - x}{y - x_1}-1\right)f(x_1) + \frac{x-x_1}{y-x_1}f(y) \\ = \frac{x-x_1}{y- x_1}(f(y) - f(x_1)),$$

and, thus,

$$\tag{2}\frac{f(x) - f(x_1)}{x-x_1} \geqslant \frac{f(y) - f(x_1)}{y-x_1}$$

In the same way for $x_1 < y < x_2$ we can show

$$\tag{3}\frac{f(y) - f(x_1)}{y-x_1} \geqslant \frac{f(x_2) - f(y)}{x_2-y}$$

Therefore, from (2) and (3) we have

$$\frac{f(x) - f(x_1)}{x-x_1} \geqslant \frac{f(x_2) - f(y)}{x_2-y}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How do I show the first inequality? Is it from the definition of concavity directly?

Comment: @Sadem:  It is and I'll add some more detail to make it clear for you.

Comment: Thank you again for your edit!